# Can I write a dinosaur onto a CD?

Tags: google-chrome, compact-disc

(No, not a real dinosaur)

In Google Chrome, there is a Dinosaur game that can be found at "chrome://dino/". (It also displays when there is no internet connection). Is it possible to put this game onto a CD (any size) such that it is playable without Chrome being installed? If so, what is the minimal size of a CD needed?

(Inspired by [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1239044/can-i-write-200-mb-150-min-music-to-a-700-mb-80-min-cd#comment1815401_1239044))

Comment: https://portableapps.com/apps/internet/google_chrome_portable :P

Comment: @TomYan While that might work, a something smaller is certainly possible. (I just edited in the size clause)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That portion of the Chromium source code has been extracted:

https://github.com/wayou/t-rex-runner

Looks like it is entirely javascript so put this on a disk and play.

Comment: This is cool, but the source is more tailored to Chrome and does not work in every browser.

Comment: @wp78de Yeah, this is the only answer, but it doesn't really address the question, which is how to get it running without chrome.  Given it is javascript, it needs at least a scripting and rendering engine, so the blink core from Chromium I guess.